# Autofill Username and Password in UIWebView Not Autofilling

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, textfield

I am having a issue parsing data from m `NSUserDefaults` to a Textfield on a `UIWebView` in my App. I am trying to pull the users Username and Password stored in another file encrypted by their TouchID. While doing some testing I have tried to figure out how to Inject that data into the Textfield but it is not working, this I can almost guarantee is by my wrong doing somewhere, and I need help finding it. After doing some research and watching videos I've been trying the follow code below, but even though it worked for others, it is not working for me. I don't know if this could be because of the websites CSS Transitions (which I can not control) or if It's a issue somewhere with how I plan to parse the data.

The website I am parsing data to is https://westernchristian.myschoolapp.com/app#login

I have also tried using this same method on Google with the search bar, but that doesn't work either.

Here is the Code I am Calling

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIWebView *web;
```

**ViewController.m**

```
-(void)loadMyWCS {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://westernchristian.myschoolapp.com/app#login"];
    //NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://google.com"];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [_web loadRequest:request];
    [self webViewDidFinishLoad:_web];

}

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSString *savedUsername = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"username"];
    [_web stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('Username').value = '%@'", savedUsername]];

}
```

Thanks for taking the time to look at my question. It has been a struggle for a couple days now to try and figure this out. I hope that it can be solved. If I made a grammatical errors or errors elsewhere I apologize. If you have any questions I will try and respond to them as soon as I can. Thank you all for taking the time to look at my code. I look forward to hearing from you!